# Average Color From Image URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the average color from a not loaded image (image URL) in Node.Js
Anyone got an idea how to?

For example, I'm trying to get the average color of [this](https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/tr5yuCd1rxFFe1sjUZjI3HOjCPifPGyIFk7EHX8pcxg/%3F1644775669/https/bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png) Image (which is yellow), but I can't. Saw some API's but those are for Typescript, doesn't really help me.

Comment: You can use any typescript api in js

Comment: You can't do any processing on an image that isn't loaded.